# Bind Pivot SelectedIndex causes app random crash Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I have an universal app for WP 8.1 with a page and a Pivot in it. The "SelectedIndex" property of the pivot is bind to a property in the VM like this:

```
public object SelectedPivotIndex
{
    get { return this.selectedPivotIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (this.selectedPivotIndex == value) return;
        this.selectedPivotIndex = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedPivotIndex);
    }
}
```

Page code:

```
<Pivot x:Name="ContentPivot"
        x:Uid="ContentPivot"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedPivotIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
    >...</Pivot>
```

The problem is from time to time i'm having app crash (in App.xaml.cs): "Unhandled exception" with type "COMEXCEPTION". This crash stop if I remove the bind of the "SelectedIndex" in the xaml, but I cannot understand why it ocurs. Sometimes even the debugger is not shown and the app closes without any error information.
BTW I'm using MVVM Light, so the "glue" between the view (page) and the VM is set in the page:

```
<Page
...
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
>
```

**EDIT:**

I'm able to reproduce the crash with this behavior: Open app, navigate to another page, come back to the pivot page (several times) and flip throught the pivotitems.

Comment: The index is an int value, why are you using object?

Comment: @Fred That was my initial type for the property, but it causes a cast exception, I don't understand why...

Comment: That's hard to tell without a stack trace. However this just looks fishy to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. Solved it by hadling the selected changed event instead. Not a solution but a workaround.

Comment: Well, just tested right now and its working as expected, no such a friendly mvvm solution, but... not my fault. BTW thanks Robert for the answer ;)

Comment: How can I get this to work the other way?? I want to change the index from the ViewModel and have the View updated, not the other way around which gets handled by the changed event workaround..

Comment: @Pam You can Always setup a event in the codebehind. Either send a message or listen to PropertyChanged.
<pre><code>
viewmodel.PropertyChanged += CodeBehindPropertyChanged;
        private void _CodeBehindPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "PivotIndex")
            {
               <do stuff>
</code></pre>